# Exit script with error code based on loop operations in bash

Tags: bash, loops, exit, exit-code

I have a wrapper script for a CI pipeline which works great, but it always returns with 0 even though subcommands in a for loop fails. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_list=("file1 file2 file_nonexistant file3")

for file in $file_list
do
  cat $file
done
```

```
>./listfiles.sh
file1 contents
file2 contents
cat: file_nonexistant: No such file or directory
file3 contents
>echo $?
>0
```

Since the last iteration of the loop is successfull the entire script exits with 0.
What i want is for the loop to continue on fail and for the script to exit 1 if any of the loop iterations returned errors.

What i have tried so far:

- `set -e` but it halts the loop and exits when an iteration fails
- replaced `done` with `done || exit 1` - no effect
- replaced `cat $file` with `cat $file || continue` - no effect

Comment: Hmm the script still returns 0 even if file_nonexistant is the last file to be iterated over. even with `done || exit 1`

Comment: `file_list=("file1 file2 file_nonexistant file3")` This is an array with one element... Why is it an array at all? Check your scripts with shellcheck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative 1

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 6`; do
    if test $i == 4; then
        z=1
    fi
done
if [[ $z == 1 ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

With files

```
#!/bin/bash

touch ab c d e
for i in a b c d e; do
    cat $i
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
        fail=1
    fi
done

if [[ $fail == 1 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

The special parameter `$?` holds the exit value of the last command. A value above 0 represents a failure. So just store that in a variable and check for it after the loop.

The $? parameter actually holds the exit status of the previous pipeline, if present. If the command is killed with a signal then the value of $? will be 128+SIGNAL. For example 128+2 in case of SIGINT (ctrl+c).

Overkill solution with trap

```
#!/bin/bash

trap ' echo X $FAIL; [[ $FAIL -eq 1 ]] && exit 22 ' EXIT

touch ab c d e
for i in  c d e a b; do
    cat $i || export FAIL=1
    echo F $FAIL
done
```

Comment: Hmm, setting a manual error flag was my first go-to aswell, and it does solve this particular issue. But isn't there a more native way of doing this using returns or try/catch or something?

Comment: try / catch is not native to bash in any way. You could run a function with `trap myfunc EXIT` and handle some state there, and exit with an arbitrary code. However, you would still rely on a variable or an env to detect the fault. You could also touch a file, and check for that...

Comment: `isn't there a more native way of doing this using returns or try/catch or something?` So you want an answer like "no, there isn't"? If you want custom behavior (catching errors and then existing the script on the end), then you have to implement it. `cat $i
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]` - use `if ! cat "$i"; then` , `if [[ $fail == 1 ]]` - in bash just `if ((fail))`